# send application to user Notifications on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the facebooker plugin in rails to let users sign up through facebook connect. the application uses iframe. Now when certain things occur,how can I send notifications to application users from the application through facebook.

Answer (score 0):

call `send_email` on the `Facebooker::User`